# Insert In PostrgeSQL array without first retrieving the array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column in PostgreSQL Table

```
modification_dates timestamp without time zone[]
```

I need to be able to add a date to the array. The easy way would be to get the array and add element then rewrite it.

Another way would be to get the array , count it and use the following syntax to set the last value.

```
UPDATE my_table SET timestamp [countOfArray] = newDate;
```

Is there a way to do it with one SQL Statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the concatenation operator or `array_cat`, as per the [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html):

```
UPDATE my_table SET timestamp = timestamp || newDate;
```

or

```
UPDATE my_table SET timestamp = array_cat(timestamp, ARRAY[newDate]);
```

where the preferred way is the former. Adding a condition will work just as it does in any other update query.

Answer (score 1):

To *append* a new value to the array use the standard SQL [concatenation operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html):

```
update my_table
   set modification_dates = modification_dates||current_timestamp
where ...;
```

You can't insert a new element in between existing elements.